# Swift: Call Function from within a different tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to call the function

```
 func setupChatLogForUser(user: ChatPartner){
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let chatLog = ChatHistory(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    chatLog.user = user
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLog, animated: true)
}
```

from within a different tab of my TabBarController.

I´m changing the tab as the first step but don´t know how to call the function with a specific user afterwards as I´m using the navigationController to push a view controller as well...

Thank´s for your help!

EDIT:

```
var chatsViewController:HomeScreen?

func chat(){
    print("Chat clicked")
    guard let chatFriends = self.friend else {return}
    print(chatFriends)

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    self.chatsViewController?.setupChatLogForUser(user: chatFriends)
}
```

Comment: Get an instance of that TabBar class from your other class and call the method.

Comment: Tried that and did not work. This works fine when calling the function from within the same tab. However, it seems to be not working when calling it from within a different tab

Comment: Show what your tried to call it please.

Comment: Wrote it right under "EDIT"

Comment: Is `self.chatsViewController?` nil?

Comment: Yes, how can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initialising the `chatsViewController` an instance of `HomeScreen` here and looks like it's nil as per your code posted. You can call the method like this without globally creating an instance

```
func chat(){
    print("Chat clicked")
    guard let chatFriends = self.friend else {return}
    print(chatFriends)

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    HomeScreen().setupChatLogForUser(user: chatFriends)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Debug it and check whether setupchatlogforuser method gets called or not

Comment: Yes, it does get called

Comment: Why don't you call the same method from with in your current Tabbarcontroller ? Don't use instance of HomeScreen

Comment: This works. But I actually want the app to go to the HomeScreen View and open it right there if it's possible.

Comment: Didn't got you. Can you please explain a bit more in detail